# Is there a word that defines describing something in the past with modern language?

Tags: word-choice

For example, Jane Austen's carriage went up and down the hills like a roller coaster.

Comment: "Anachronistic"?

Comment: It seems @EdwinAshworth is correct... at least according to my interpretation of the question.

Comment: This isn't about an *actual* anachronism, but a word that describes an anachronistic metaphor. I'd say it's different enough a question, even if it gets basically the same answer.

Comment: As you say, it is an adjective that describes an anachronistic metaphor.  I read it somewhere and cannot pull it out of my brain.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Anachronism is a word which describes chronological inconsistency.

[Anachronism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism)

"An anachronism (from the Greek ἀνά ana, "against" and χρόνος khronos, "time"), is a chronological inconsistency in some arrangement, especially a juxtaposition of person(s), events, objects, or customs from different periods of time."